# Should I develop mobile web app over native app for each platform for what I intend to do

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-website

I'm looking to develop a mobile app which is going to help people find out whether a train is going to go to a particular platform or not.It is very simple. I know the timetables. I'll be making database of train timings and compare with the timings of user, when he uses the app and tell him, if the next train coming at the station he's at, is going to this platform at location X or not.

There won't be any fancy UI. There would be a dropdown of all stations. That's it. Response from the app will be going to platform no A. I don't know if I will include any feature as of now. The requirement that I see is, app should be offline and platform agnostic.The database entries are fixed and if they change then I should be able to give a new update.I have been reading about HTML5, but I don't want people to use the Internet for this. It should be available on Nokia phones,Android phones, Blackberry,Apple in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offline and platform agnostic will be hard to combine, unless you use one of the toolkits that pretend to do this (we started that way, but reverted - cost more time to chase bugs in the toolkit than to write code). Easiest is you give up the first requirement - most people with smart phones will have data bundles anyway, a tiny query is not going to make them frown.

Assuming you're not dropping the requirement, HTML5 for the UI can still be an option as most platforms let you embed the browser in your app. That way, you'd only need to port some small wrapper code and the business logic. If it's a commercial app, pick one or two key platforms (that will give you the necessary user feedback to make your app better) and outsource porting of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one... I'd choose native programming. Id just have all the different platforms linked so they use the exact same database. Unfortunately, they all use different programming languages. I don't know about Nokia or Blackberry, but Android uses Java (or C# through MonoDroid) while Iphones/Ipods use Obj-C (or C# through MonoTouch).

Comment: @cdegroot, what if the user has an IPod Touch and a normal flip phone...?

Comment: Going native would incredibly delay this. I can do this app in a day on html5. The only problem is the country(India) I stay in not everyone has Internet on their phones yet

Comment: You when the app installs, you can set it to just unpack itself and work like a web page, just completely downloaded onto the device. Unfortunately, you won't be able to use the database without php... I still say native, but with shared source code.